# Disable "Driving Off" notification on MacOS

Tags: macos, notifications, sonoma

I came back from lunch today, and went back to work (OK, not really "work", I was reading Stack Overflow) on my MacBook Pro. About 10 minutes later, I got a "Driving off" notification on the MacBook. My iPhone 15 disconnected from my car (which has Apple CarPlay) a while ago, why is the notification coming now? And why does it show on my computer at all?

This doesn't happen most times I come back from driving, but it's happened once or twice before.

Can I prevent this? I looked in Notifications settings, I didn't see anything that seemed relevant. The only setting related to driving is Focus.